# SignalR's $.hubConnection() is not a function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, signalr

Hi All i'm working on Implementing a SignalR Stock Ticker Using AngularJS based on an [example over here](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-signalr-stock). But i'm getting an  error while connecting to signalr like this **TypeError: $.hubConnection is not a function**

And this is where the error is showing:

```
var initializeClient = function () {
      //Creating connection and proxy objects
       console.log("anil");
       connection = $.hubConnection();
       //console.log("anil.r");
       proxy = connection.createHubProxy('stockTicker');

       configureProxyClientFunctions();

       start();
        };
```

Since I'm new to working  on signalr , have got lots of confusion in it can anybody help me out  of this .

Comment: Have you included jquery.signalR.min.js?

Comment: @Marcus H u mean in  my index page

Comment: @Marcus H now i'm  getting the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Comment: From my app.js page

Comment: var start = function () {
            //Starting the connection and initializing market
            connection.start().pipe(function () {
                initializeStockMarket();
            });
        };

Comment: Yes, you need to add script reference to the index.html

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install -s signalr
2. Add the next lines to angular-cli.json

   ```
   "scripts": [

   ...
   "../node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"

   ],
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure it is added, if your project version Angular 6+ add the next lines to angular.json
2. Re-compile project.

> ```
> "scripts": [
>
> ...
>
> "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", 
>
> "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js" 
>
>
> ],
> ```