# jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.hubConnection is not a function

Tags: jquery, angular, signalr, angular8

I am trying to get singlar (non ASP.Core one) to work with angular 8

If I just add the signalr an jquery to index.html like so

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/signalr@2.4.1/jquery.signalR.min.js"></script>
```

everything works fine. I would however rather it worked packaged with webpack like everything else so I went to my package.json and installed signalr

`"signalr": "2.4.1"` (I double checked in npm did install jquery signalr package depends on)

Then added `import * as $ from 'jquery';` to the service where I do signalr communication. All of the sudden I get the error

`jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.hubConnection is not a function`

Comment: Have you tried with `import { jQuery, $ }  from 'jquery'` ?
Moreover https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890506/signalrs-hubconnection-is-not-a-function?rq=1 seems to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this into where signalr is being initialized

`declare var $: any;`

and then this into

`angular.json -> projects -> architect -> build -> options`

`"scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js" ],`