# jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.hubConnection is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, signalr

I am using jQuery and signalR with React and Storybook just fine. However when I use the the default webpack dev server with React, I get the error:

> jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.hubConnection is not a function

When I google this issue, all the solutions seem to relate to use with Angular and suggest updating Angular config, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890506/signalrs-hubconnection-is-not-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173154/jquery-webpack-imported-module-4-hubconnection-is-not-a-function).

I have this in `webpack.dev.js`:

```js
    plugins: [
      new ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      }),
```

I am using jQuery 3.3.1 and signalR 2.3.0.

What needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I had to add this to the file where signalR was being used in my TypeScript file:

```js
declare global {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  interface Window { jQuery: any }
}

window.jQuery = $;
require('signalr');
```