# Angular11 - SignalR $.hubConnection() is not a function

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am using Angular 11.0.4, and trying to create connection with server from angular client. But getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.hubConnection is not a function
```

I have installed jQuery ("jquery": "^3.6.0") , and SignalR ("signalr": "^2.4.3")

I checked the similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890506/signalrs-hubconnection-is-not-a-function?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57173154/jquery-webpack-imported-module-4-hubconnection-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018350/jquery-webpack-imported-module-0-default-a-hubconnection-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1), but no luck.

Inside `angular.json`, I placed these lines in `scripts` array.

```
 "scripts": [
              ...
   
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", 

              "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js" 
            ]
```

Angular code:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var hub1Proxy = connection.createHubProxy('hub1');
hub1Proxy.on('mymethod', function(name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
});
```

All these changes could not help to get rid of above error.

Server Side Hub is defined in `.Net Framework 4.7.2 MVC Project`.

Can anybody suggest, what is missing here?

Comment: i'm running into a similar bug as well, though i dont believe "angular" tag has anything to do with the issue, as it's strictly jquery+signalr. The only other piece i could come up with is, either switching to .net core, or downgrading to an older version of signalr for framework... (i havent attempted yet, but i'm brainstorming)

Comment: Yes, I believe switching to .net core will work, but I could not switch because of my current project stack.

Comment: have anyone find solution

Answer (score 0):

**In .ts file:**
*Do not use "Microsoft/SignalR" for .net framework*

declare var $: any;

this.connection = $.hubConnection("connection url");

In **package.json**, include in dependencies:
"signalr": "^2.4.3",